# Is there a creative way to pass in multiple arguments to contentEquals() method?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

As I understand, the contentEquals() method only accepts one argument to be compared with.
In the following program, what if I wanted to pass in more?

like: 
(1)YES 
(2)Yes 
(3)Y 
(4)y

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ifStatement1 {

    public static void main(String[]  args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Want some pizza?");

        String userInput = input.nextLine();

        boolean answer = **userInput.contentEquals("yes");**

        if(answer) {
            System.out.println("so go take a break from all this code");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("so keep writing code");
        }   

    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit? Are you defining the `contentEquals` method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; I declare a boolean and assign it via a comparison of the userInput and contentsEquals("yes").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Set.of("YES", "Yes", "Y", "y").contains(userInput)
```

`String.equals` would be more normal than using `String.contentEquals` with a `String`.

Comment: Piggybacking off of this, you can also reduce the amount of items you need in the Set by doing something like `Set.of("yes", "y").contains(userInput.toLowerCase());` then it can be any combination of different casing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean answer;
        if(Set.of("yes","y").contains(userInput.toLowerCase())){
            answer = true;
        } else {
            answer = false;
        }
        System.out.print(answer);
    }
}
```